# Rails 4 + Capistrano 2: How to not precompile assets if they're not changed?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, capistrano, assets

I am using Rails 4 in combination with Capistrano 2 and everything works great. A few days later, I added the `ckeditor` editor to my app. When I deploy the code to the server now, it takes 15 minutes to get done.

Is there any way to precompile assets only if they were detected to be changed?

Or, is there any other satisfying solution to solve this problem?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This problem should be minimal on Rails 4 due to changes in the way the asset pipeline cache is used. In Rails 3 there's a gem, Turbo Sprockets, to address the problem.

If you want to completely avoid asset compilation unless there is a change you could either use directly or follow the approach used by the [recap](https://github.com/tomafro/recap) gem.

Specifically take a look at:

https://github.com/freerange/recap/blob/master/lib/recap/tasks/rails.rb